# Camunda Executionlistener implementation with timestamp

Tags: java, camunda

hey guys im very new to camunda, i want to measure the execution time for my process from start to end but i can't find a proper coding example for the listener. All i could come up with is

```
public void notify (DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {

    // What happens when Start Event is executed
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // What happens when token has reached End Event
    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
    System.out.println(elapsedTime);
    }
```

i set the class in the modeler for the start and end event which i hope is right.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The engine measure for you. But you can't print the duration of a process instance with a listener into the process, because the process instance is still running. You can check the duration in the database table *act_hi_procinst*.

Also you can use the HistoryService from the engine:

```
public class ProcessInstanceHistory {

@Inject
HistoryService historyService;

public List<HistoricProcessInstance> historicProcessInstances() {
    return historyService.createHistoricProcessInstanceQuery().list();
}

public void printDurations() {
    for (HistoricProcessInstance historicProcessInstance : historicProcessInstances()) {
        System.out.println("elapsedTime :" + historicProcessInstance.getDurationInMillis());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in the process end-to-end execution time, you can just check the HistoricActivityInstance via historyService and check its start and end date.
No need for custom implementation.